# ERROR in The loader /src/app/app.component.scss didn't return a string

Tags: webpack, angular6

[image]

I got this issue after config sass-loader to my webpack and I did search some solution for it but look like not work.
Can anyone help me. Thank you!

Here is my webpack.config.js file. I configured myself from scratch.

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ScriptExtPlugin = require('script-ext-html-webpack-plugin');
const { AngularCompilerPlugin } = require('@ngtools/webpack');


module.exports = function () {
  return {
    entry: './src/main.ts',
    output: {
      path: __dirname + '/dist',
      filename: 'app.js'
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    performance: {
      maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
      maxAssetSize: 512000
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        { test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ['@ngtools/webpack'] },
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
        { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [{
            loader: "css-loader", options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }, {
            loader: "sass-loader", options: {
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }]
        },
        // Ignore warnings about System.import in Angular
        { test: /[\/\\]@angular[\/\\].+\.js$/, parser: { system: true } },
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets' }
      ]),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: __dirname + '/src/index.html',
        output: __dirname + '/dist',
        inject: 'head'
      }),

      new ScriptExtPlugin({
        defaultAttribute: 'defer'
      }),
      new AngularCompilerPlugin({
        tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
        entryModule: './src/app/app.module#AppModule',
        sourceMap: true
      })

    ]
  };
}
```

I think the issue come from the way I configured sass to my project but I didn't know what it is.

Comment: use html-loader instead of raw-loader for html files

Answer (score 4):

You need to add [css-to-string-loader](https://github.com/smithad15/css-to-string-loader) after css-loader. Also, as Luillyfe mentioned, you should use html-loader for html.

```
{
  // For Angular template html
  test: /\.html$/,
  use: 'html-loader'
},
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: [
    'css-to-string-loader',
    {loader: 'css-loader', options: {sourceMap: true}},
    {loader: 'sass-loader', options: {sourceMap: true}}
  ]
},
```